# How to install a language which is not shown under "installed languages"?

Tags: keyboard, language-support, input, source

I need to use "Greek Polytonic". After installing Ubuntu 20.04 recently on my new computer, it does not show "Greek Polytonic" or any kind of Greek for that matter under "input sources". How can I use a language which is not "installed"?

[image]

Comment: @24601: Well, the OP wondered how to add it from the GUI, didn't they?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to have `fonts-sil-galatia` installed then use the above suggestion if the keyboard does not work with it. The package name should be similar in Ubuntu.

```
root@buster-raspi:~# apt-cache search Greek Polytonic
fonts-pecita - OpenType hand-written font whose letters are connected
fonts-sil-galatia - font family for Latin-1 and Greek (polytonic support)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's there. Probably you have a Greek locale installed, and in that case you should see a *Greek* item in a previous window. If you click *Greek*, it will expand and give you a few Greek options including *Greek (polytonic)*.